# Python: when I read a CSV file's row and then write it to a separate CSV file, it all goes into one cell

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook

Let's say input.csv has one row like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

Let's also say that output.csv is empty, but I want it to contain

```
numbers:,1,2,3,4,5
```

I'd use the code:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as out:
    wr = csv.writer(out, delimiter=',', lineterminator = '\n')
    with open('input.csv',"rt") as in:
        for line in csv.reader(in, delimiter=','):
            wr.writerow(['numbers:',line])
```

However, when I do this, output.csv contains:

```
 numbers:,"[1,2,3,4,5]"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aside: that can't be your code, because `in` is a keyword and so can't be used as a variable name.  When asking questions, please post an actual [mcve], not just code which resembles the one giving you problems.

Answer (score 0):

`writerow` takes an array and writes each element of that array to the CSV file. You passed two values: 'numbers:' and an array of what you read from the other file. It's just like you called this:

```
w.writerow(['a', ['b', 'c', 'd']])
```

which writes: `a,"['b', 'c', 'd']"`.

You want just `wr.writerow(line)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to combine 'numbers:' and your line from original file to one list. To do that you can use list concatenation. 
I would rewrite the last line of your script in the following way:

```
row = ['numbers:'] + line
wr.writerow(row)
```